# Switch easily between maven-2 and maven-3 builds on Windows

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

I have the following use case: I am using maven-3 to build most of my projects, but I have projects built with maven-2 too. Because I am on Windows, it is very annoying to edit my M2_HOME system variable to point to maven-2 or maven-3 installation dir depending on what maven I have to use in order to build my project.

Is there a better way of switching between maven-2 and maven-3 on Windows?

Comment: Is it a problem to migrate the Maven 2 projects to Maven 3 ?

Comment: No, it's not a problem. The question aims to find a more general solution to this problem. I was thinking about some script, which could invoke only maven-2 - setting m2_home as first step. This way I do not have to touch system variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I have declared M2_HOME variable under System variables. This post http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Why-does-maven-3-still-use-the-M2-HOME-variable-td4611146.html helped me to understand that I can just use MAVEN_HOME pointing to my maven-3 installation dir, and refer to maven-2 by specifying the path to its bin dir which is a better solution than switching between maven-2 and maven-3 in Environments variables section